# How to determine the visibility of a target at a fixed height above an observer on a given DEM?

Tags: dem, viewshed, visibility

I have a DEM, an observer position and an observer height above ground. Further I have a fixed height above the observer at which a flying target is expected. I now want to determine given the DEM, the observer and the object height all positions on the map where the observer can see the target at that particular fixed height.

I am not sure what kind of algorithm to look at exactly.

I have looked into viewshed algorithms but I can only find algorithms that determine the target height relative to the DEM at each location (not only relative to the observer height).

I also looked at algorithms that determine the visible horizon which is better.

But maybe someone with more experience has a better idea, what I should look into.

Comment: You don't say which software you are using, edit your question to include this, license levels and any extensions you have installed.

Comment: This could help you @sehan2 https://github.com/mkondratyev85/raster_tracer

Comment: @Hornbydd I was not thinking of a particular software. I am looking for an approach to the concrete problem.

Comment: @Timothy Dalton I am sorry to say this but I think the plugin is no solution since I want to find the visibility region.

Comment: Depending on your software (and your extensions as it is Esri), the visibility toolset offered by Esri in ArcGIS Pro can be useful. It reports either the Frequency or the number of observer points, as defined by the analysis_type.